# Lacie 2big network: can't connect, tells me to reconnect in a few minutes

Tags: nas

My Lacie 2big network NAS is acting weird.
When I visit the web admin page, it is loading for a while and then stops telling me to reconnect in a minute.

When I use the Lacie network assistant and go to Volumes and click the Authentication button and enter my user details, it says that it could not list volumes as admin and that I have to check authentication.

I've tried a couple of methods to reset the disk to its factory default settings:

> 1. Switch OFF the product.
>      (Once OFF, the product's back power switch MUST be on the OFF position.)
> 2. PUSH the front button and KEEP IT PRESSED.
> 3. MOVE the back power switch to the ON position.
>         (The front button's LED will start blinking Blue & Red.)
> 4. Once the front button's LED stops blinking and is stable RED, 
>      RELEASE the front button.
>      (Once released, the front button's LED will start blinking Blue.)
> 5. When the front button's LED stops blinking again and is stable Blue, PUSH the front button and RELEASE it. This confirms the reset/
> 6. Leave product rebooting, you are done. (The product is now restoring itself to its factory defaults.)

but that didn't work out either.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked in my case:

After the last reset I waited a couple of hours and kept trying to get the login screen.
Then, all of sudden, the login screen appeared. I was able to login using my own username and password.
I then removed the NAS from the domain. After that I made sure that the NAS time and Domain time were exactly the same. I then joined the domain using the fully qualified domain name.

I received an error that it could not join the domain. However, I can now login using my domain username and password.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same prob a few times over the years. Two things I've done that seem to fix it:

1. Reboot the computer, which re-loads the Lacie Network Assistant (sometimes finds the named NAS sometimes it just indicates the IP address) - I've done this 3-4 times before it actually mounts the drives for access. I think it may be a boot order thing (PC -> netork -> NAS vs NAS -> network -> PC - the later seems to be what it needs). Note: just reloading the Lacie Network Assistant doesn't seem to help...
2. Leave it for ~1 hour - after giving up rebooting a few times (both PC and Lacie NAS - just the "blue-eye" button), leave it all on, and come back ~1 hour later. Sometimes the Lacie Network Assistant is running, sometimes it has shutdown (by itself). I can then access my NAS drives - so I'm good... (apart from wasting 1-2 hours).

Note: I try to leave the Lacie NAS on 24/7 as the problem almost always occurs if I've powered off the Lacie NAS.

Answer (score 0):

had the same yesterday, tried the above + procedure to reset as described on the lacie website (which differs slightly for the last step) Nothing helped. Contacted Lacie: This was their respons:

- Can you try to just type the ipadres
  in the webinterface instead of
  clicking on the link to acces it?
  Sometimes that solves the problem.
  Espacially after an update . The dns
  name is sometimes disturbed

Tried their suggestion, did not work, their next respons was:

- If the device can't be resetted, i'm afraid that the only solution then is to send in the drive for checkup and repair.

Since I just bought this NAS, i have decided not to send it in for repair but to return it and go for a different brand